# How to load JSON formatted data to BigQuery table using Python in Airflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to append data to bigquery table using python operator in airflow. When the task run, I'm getting below errors

> ERROR - Could not serialize the XCom value into JSON. If you are using pickles instead of JSON for XCom, then you need to enable pickle support for XCom in your airflow config.

> ERROR - Object of type 'LoadJob' is not JSON serializable

Python Code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

def load_pg_data_to_bq(**kwargs):
    with open("dags/prod_data_sync_bucket/airtimes_.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
        json_object = json.load(json_data)

    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = r"dags\keys\service_key.json"

    ### Converts schema to BigQuery's expected format, 
    table_schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("phone_number", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("request_id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("created_at", "DATETIME", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("updated_at", "DATETIME", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("amount", "FLOAT64", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("bq_updatetime", "DATETIME", mode="NULLABLE")
        ]

    project_id = <MY_PROJECT_ID>
    dataset_id = <MY_DATASET_ID>
    table_id = <MY_TABLE_ID>

    client  = bigquery.Client(project = project_id)
    dataset  = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table = dataset.table(table_id)

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
        schema=table_schema,
    )
    job = client.load_table_from_json(json_object, table, job_config = job_config)

    print(job.result())
    return job.result()
```

What I'm I missing?

Comment: I tried running your code in Airflow and got the same error as you have mentioned in the question. To isolate the issue, I tried running the same code using the BigQuery client library outside the Airflow environment and it ran successfully. So, the problem lies on the Airflow side. Please create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Aprovider%3AGoogle) in the Airflow repository explaining the problem.